# @JsonSerialize on @Controller @RequestMapping

Tags: serialization, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm return a Java object from an @Controller but I'd like to invoke a Jackson serializer on this particular method. At the moment this isn't given errors but the serializer isn't being invoked either. An alternative is to attach the @JsonSerialize on the class of the returning object, but I was wondering if I needed to make some changes to the following code to get it to work:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=SimpleShiftAllocSerializer.class, as=HashMap.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/shifts/readAlloc.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, ? extends Object> readAlloc(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
    return someObjectToSerialise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming your are using mvc namespace configuration, if jackson is available on the class path the org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is automatically registered as HttpMessageConverter.

*AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser:312*

```
if (jacksonPresent) {
    messageConverters.add(createConverterBeanDefinition(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class, source));
}
```

so when a @ResponseBody annotated controller method returns, it checks whether if there is any  registered HttMessageConverter that supports the returned type and ContentType (HttpMessageConverter.canWrite()) and if so, its write method will be invoked.

it don't think that the Jackson MessageConvert supports

```
Map<String, ? extends Object>
```

either put that map in a WrapperBean (with json annotations) or implement your own HttpMessageConverter (don't forget to register it)

Comment: Thanks, I've already defined a custom Jackson converters in my root-context.xml and that generic Map type is being serialised into JSON. My problem is that the Jackson serialiser I've provided isn't being invoked - I'm not getting any error messages, and the JSON output doesn't change with or without the @JsonSerialize.

Comment: MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter won't be invoked unless the Accept Request Header is application/json.

Comment: yes it seems to be returning that anyhow... I've just transformed my objects in a separate class and return those. I realised that Jackson's serializers should not be used to transform data, since changing to a different JSON library would mean your controllers would be returning invalid JSON! Thanks for giving a few tips though.